# how do I target the second span in a list?

Tags: html, css

I am trying align the food prices on top of each other for the menu section for food on page. I placed the price in a span within the li of food, it worked for first span but not the others.

I know about nth-child but its not working. Did just right it wrong ?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Gsimelus92/z8dna4c2/3/

```css
.apett-left ul li:nth-child(1) {
          margin-bottom:5px;
          font-size: 19px;
          font-weight: bold;
         }

     .apett-left span:nth-child(1){
          color: #AA8A45;
          margin-left:130px;
         }

     .apett-left ul li:nth-child(2) {
          margin-bottom:5px;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          border-bottom-style: dotted;
          border-color: white;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
         }

     .apett-left span:nth-child(2){
          color: #AA8A45;
          margin-left:130px;
            }


         /********************foodder and price 2 ******/


     .apett-left ul li:nth-child(3) {
          margin-bottom:5px;
          font-size: 19px;
          font-weight: bold;
         }

     .apett-left ul li:nth-child(4) {
          margin-bottom:5px;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          border-bottom-style: dotted;
          border-color: white;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

     .apett-left span:nth-child(2){
          color: #AA8A45;
          margin-left:200px;    
         }
```

```html
   <section class="pat-a">
      <div class="apett-pic">
        <img src="bbq-nachos.jpg"width="800" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="apett-food">
          <div class="apett-left">
             <ul>
               <li>Mozzarella Sticks <span>$7.00</span></li>
               <li>Add pulled pork /homemade chilli / bbq beans <span>$1.50</span></li>
                      
               <li>Boneless Wing <span>$0.00</span></li>
               <li>Plain / spicy / sticky bbq <span>$0.00</span></li>

               <li>biscuits & bbq beans</li>
               <li>each bicuite</li>
             </ul>                        
          </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: there is no second span in your li ...

Comment: I suggest using a `table` element for tabluar data such as this.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to select the second child `span`, but there is no second child, only first. Both `span` are the first child of their `li` elements.
Instead of selecting the first and second `span`, try to select the first and second `li`, and then `span` inside, like this:

```
.apett-left ul li:nth-child(1) span {
    /* code */
 }
.apett-left ul li:nth-child(2) span {
    /* code */
 }
```